# I have table in autocad but drawn as lines. I wanted to export this table into execl sheet

Tags: autocad

I have table in autocad but drawn as lines. I wanted to export this table into execl sheet. Itried to group the lines to make it table and tried to export it to execl but i failed.
The picture is attaced.
![the table][1]

Comment: Your image is missing.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If the table is comprised of mtext & line objects rather than a table object. then you may want to write a program that takes a complete selection, collects only the text objects. Then starting with the text that is in the upper left quadrant and moving right append the text in a string separated to generate a csv file. If you have exploded mtext objects, it adds to the algorithm complexity as you have to distinguish those cells content.

Also it would be helpful to have that picture.